# Как решить ошибку в коде?

Tags: pascal

Программа на pascal. IDE отмечает ошибку в 13 строке.

```
program mas;
uses CRT;
var A: array of integer;
n, i, min, ind, tf: integer;
begin
Clrscr;
write('Укажите размерность массива: ');
read(n);
SetLength(A, n);
writeln('Заполните массив: ');
for i:=1 to n do
begin
write(i,' элемент: ');
read(A[i]); //-------------------------Здесь-------------------------- 
end;
min:=A[1];
for i:=1 to n do
begin
if min>A[i] then
begin
ind:=i;
end;
end;
tf:=ind mod 2;
if tf = 1 then
writeln('Верно')
else
writeln('Не верно');
end.
```

Comment: А текст ошибки какой? Мы должны скомпилить, что бы получить ошибку?

Comment: P.S Писать все сплошным текстом не есть гуд. Программу структурируют табуляцией, что бы отчетливо была видна структура.

Comment: @iluxa1810
Line 13 dgc.pas Runtime pascal exception.
Caused by: length=4; index=4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Элементы динамического массива нумеруются с нуля, так что последний имеет индекс `n-1`. Исправить:

```
for i := 0 to n - 1 do
```

В общем случае для обработки всех элементов

```
for i := 0 to High(A) do
или
for i := 0 to Length(A) - 1  do
```

Где-то в программе ещё может быть код, который подразумевает 1-based массив.

Comment: @Bogdan Статические массивы - с любого счётного (даже отрицательного или char). Строки с единицы (в новых версиях можно переключать).  Динамические массивы (как у автора)  - только с нуля.

Comment: Тогда уж `for i := Low(A) to High(A) do` и вообще не думать о том, с чего этот массив начинается.